# JSoup parse trashing Freemarker tags

Tags: java, html, jsoup, freemarker

I am using JSoup to update some server-side HTML templates that have some Freemarker tags in them. JSoup doesn't recognise the Freemarker tags as valid HTML (fair enough) and converts them to `&gt;` and `&lt;` For example:

```
<div class="row">
<#list things as thing> 
</#list>
</div>
```

gets converted to:

```
<div class="row">
&lt;#list things as thing&gt;
&lt;/#list&gt;
</div>
```

when I call `Document doc = Jsoup.parse( theHtml );`

I know JSoup has a Whitelist and presumably I can add `<#list>` and other Freemarker tags to that but I don't see a way to pass the updated Whitelist to the `parse()` method?

Answer (score 3):

No, unfortunately the Whitelist feature only works for the clean() method, not the parser. So you can't add your tags easily.

Even if you use the xmlParser it will not work, since you have a tag name starting with `#`.

The only solution I see is to transform the template prior parsing. e.g. with regular expressions.

Answer (score 3):

There's a workaround that might work for you: FreeMarker has an alternative syntax where you use `[` and `]` instead of `<` and `>`, like in `[#list things as thing]`. It can be enabled in the FreeMarker configuration with the `tagSyntax` setting. (Or, if you start a template with `[#ftl]`, it will switch to the alternative syntax forcefully.)